# Enable Trigger builds remotely (e.g., from scripts) option in Jenkins pipeline

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

I want to create a Jenkins job using the Pipeline script method. I want this job to have the configuration option that allows it to be executed remotely. I am not able to find any information about how to do that. Can somebody point me in the right direction?